# Spring - excluding a bean being scanned by a parent class' configuration

Tags: java, spring

In Spring, is there a way to exclude a bean that is being scanned by some configuration in a parent class?

I have the following scenario:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.foo")
public class Config {}

@ContextConfiguration(classes = Config.class)
public abstract class A {}

public class B extends A {}
```

The `Config` class is causing some bean `com.foo.X` to be scanned, but I want to exclude it in the context of class B.

In my specific scenario, `A` and `B` are test classes. I want my test class `B` to be able to extend `A`, and thus inherit the `Config` spring configuration, but I want to be able to exclude some specific classes from being scanned. Is this possible using Spring, or will I have to remove the `@Component` annotation from the classes I want to exclude?

I have tried attempting to override the configuration and using `@ComponentScan(excludeFilters=...)` but that did not work.

Comment: Generally, in this case it's better to put your base configuration in one class and then use `@Import` to compose them.

Comment: @Profile might be what you're looking for.  http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html

Comment: Not sure I understand completly, but how about placing the classes you want excluded in a different package? Will that work for your case? Otherwise I agree profiling might be a good solution too.

Comment: @chrylis In this case, it might be possible to use `@Import`. I'd still like to see if it's possible to do this with inherited configurations though.

Comment: @IgnacioÍñigo Unfortunately, I cannot use a different package (the parent component scan is quite broad).

Comment: @jmw5598 I had considered profiles, but I don't think it will fit my case either.